# Perl - Mojolicious - Print undef key in template

Tags: perl, mojolicious

To give some context my controller selects an array ref from a query. Then the results get printed in the template like this.

home.html.ep

```
 <td> <%= @$query_result[0]->{data} %> </td>    
 <td> <%= @$query_result[1]->{data} %> </td>  
 ....  
 <td> <%= @$query_result[27]->{data} %> </td>
```

Due to some results not existing, Mojolicious throws an error ( can't use undef hash value ... )
What I am trying to do:
When Mojolicious gets to the undef hash key/value to print 'No Data'.
I have tried like this :

```
  <td> <%= @$query_result[27]->{data} || 'no data' %> </td>   
  or    
  <td> % (exists(@$query_result[27]->{data})) ? <%= @$query_result[27]->{data} %> : 'no data' </td>   
  or 
  <td>
  % if (exists($query_result[27]->{data})) {
  <%= $query_result[27]->{data} %>
  % } else { 
  'No data'
  % }
```

I can't just remove <%= $query_result[27]->{data} %> because its returned from a query that runs on different parameters and only some parameters dont return the 27th array.

Is there a way to achieve what im trying? Thank you!

Comment: Try this: `<td> <%= exists $query_result[27]->{data} ? @{$query_result[27]->{data}} :  'no data' %> </td>`

Comment: This seems not to work:    
Global symbol "@query_result" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @query_result"?) at template   
Did you mean this? <td><%= $query_result->[27] ? @$query_result[27]->{data} : 'no data' </td>

Comment: Just as a note, `@$query_result[27]->{data}` is a little bit of nonsense; it's saying to dereference $query_result and take a list slice, of a list with just the element 27. What you meant was `$$query_result[27]->{data}` which would be more commonly written as `$query_result->[27]{data}` (arrows between brackets are optional). Remember that the type of brackets determine the data structure you're dereferencing as, the sigil determines whether you're retrieving a single element or a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to show all the indexes from `0` to `27`, or less. You probably want to use a loop for that.

```
% foreach my $i ( 0 .. scalar @$query_result ) {
<td> <%= @$query_result[$i]->{data} %> </td>    
% }
```

Now you don't have to care about the number of columns any more. Do the same for the headings and you're golden.

---

Alternatively, you need to check if there is something in `$query_result->[27]` before you can do an `exists` check, because an `undef` (i.e. *no value*) cannot be used like a hash reference.

```
<td><%= $query_result->[27] ? @$query_result[27]->{data} : 'no data' </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this is what im looking for.   

     <td><%= $query_result->[27] ? @$query_result[27]->{data} : 'no data' </td>     
is there a shorter way to write this?

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily a prettier way: `($query_result->[27] // {data => 'no data'})->{data}`